# Updating a Tkinter Image Button trough user input

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to update the image from an image button through file dialog. The input from the user should be saved in a text file and then applied to the image button.

```
#imports
from ast import Lambda
from cProfile import label
from fileinput import filename
from tkinter import Entry, filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os
import shutil
 
import time
 
#define the first tk window
window = Tk()
window.geometry("655x600")
window.title("test")
window.resizable(False, False)
 
 
window.config(background="#2e3033")
 
global file12
with open("data12.txt", 'r') as file12:
    imgdata12 = file12.read().replace('\n', '')
 
def save_data12(data):
    with open("data12.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(data)
 
 
 
 
def new_window12():
    window13 = Toplevel()
    window13.geometry("500x100+200+300")
    window13.config(background="#2e3033")
    window13.title("Edit Button 12")
    Button12 = Button(window13, text="save",command=lambda: [save_data12(entry12.get()),window13.destroy()])
    Button12.place(x=5,y=70)
    entry12 = Entry(window13,width=100, font= ("Arial",12))
    entry12.place(x=5,y=30)
    browse_button12 = Button(window13, text="Change image", command=lambda: [browser12(), window13.destroy()])
    browse_button12.place(x=50, y=70)
 
streamdex_image12 = PhotoImage(file=imgdata12)
streamdex_button12 = Button(window, text="hello" , command=new_window12 , image=streamdex_image12)
streamdex_button12.place(x=500,y=380)
 
def browser12():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="select an Image File" ,filetypes=(("PNG File","*.png"),("JPG File", "*.jpg")))
    with open(".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file12:
        file12.write(filepath)
    change()
 
def change():
    file12.close()
    with open("data/image_input/data12.txt", 'r') as file:
        imgdata12 = file.read().replace('"', '')
 
    streamdex_button12.place_forget()
    streamdex_image13 = PhotoImage(file=imgdata12)
    streamdex_button13 = Button(window, text="hello" , command=new_window12 , image=streamdex_image12)
    streamdex_button13.place(x=500,y=380)
    print("test")
 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't add garbage characters to the question.

Comment: It wouldn’t let me post without them but thanks for trying to improve this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had to global the image like this:

```
def browser4():
    filepath4 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="select an Image File" ,filetypes=(("PNG File","*.png"),("JPG File", "*.jpg")))
    with open("data/image_input/data4.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(filepath4)
    global streamdex_image4
    streamdex_image4.config(file=filepath4)
```